# Puppeteer "Execution context was destroyed, most likely because of a navigation"

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, dropdown

I am facing this problem in puppeteer when i try to select a item in a dropdown list. Can someone help me?

this is the inspect section of the dropdown list on the site:

[image: this is the inspect section of the dropdown list on the site]

a image from the list:

[image: a image from the list]

this is the code i've wrote:

```
await page.select('#ClienteMonitor','VIVO VENDER B2C');
```

Comment: what happens after `await page.select('#ClienteMonitor','VIVO VENDER B2C');` ?

Comment: This isn't enough code to reproduce the issue. Please provide a runnable [mcve]. Thanks.

Comment: I think you should provide value not the text `await page.select('#ClienteMonitor','442');
`

Comment: @Akber Iqbal
The page crashes, and i get the error: "Execution context was destroyed, most likely because of a navigation" :/

Comment: @ggorlen i'm sorry. i'am new in this word, i'll provide

Comment: @Madhawa Priyashantha the page crashes as well :(